# Best practice to authenticate an ashx request

Tags: silverlight, authentication, ashx

I have a Silverlight application from which I have to call a ASHX file, something like this GetFile.ashx?orderId=4

The problem is that I want to allow this call to be made only through the application, and thus I thought of using some sort of authentication (sending the username+pass from silverlight) when calling the ashx file. I don't want to add them in the query string. Any other suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is to turn on ASP.Net authorization by whatever means are suitable for you.

If your users log in through an AuthenticationService in the Silverlight client, or through an ASP.Net page, you will be able to access the CurrentUser object from the HttpContext in your handler and from there do whatever checks you want.

The following link should get you started on finding more info if you need [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560702%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)